# Conda Python environment missing DLL file on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I created a new Conda environment on Windows:
`conda create --name recco networkx`

I then activated it with `source activate`. So far so good. Running `conda list` verifies that I have installed:

```
decorator 4.0.4
msvc_runtime 1.0.1
networkx 1.10
python 3.5.1
```

Ok, let's run `python --version` to make sure that everything is as it should be:

[image: error]

What does that even mean? When I `deactivate` and run `python --version` everything runs as expected and I'm handed back `Python 3.4.1`.

Comment: This issue was previously reported [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/443). For now I duct-taped it by downgrading my Python version in the install to Python 3.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because something is going wrong with the msvc_runtime package.  That package should contain these DLLs.  Can you please verify the contents of your environment's root folder?  These DLLs should live both in there, and in (prefix)/Library/bin.

One possible cause might be the wrong version of msvc_runtime: it should say [vc14] somewhere in `conda list` output for Python 3.5.x, and [vc10] for 3.4.x

One other cause might be that PATH is wrong after activation, and you're not picking up the DLLs correctly.  Are you using cmd.exe or powershell?  We don't support powershell yet - only cmd.exe is known to work.  If using cmd.exe, can you post the output of `echo %PATH%` please?

Comment: The contents of `(...)\Library\bin` does indeed consist of a large number of `dll` files, none of which is the `vcruntime140.d11` at issue here. `msvc_runtime 1.0.1` is present in the Python 3.4.x environment, with `[vc10]` attached to it, as expected. Running `conda` with `python=3.5` populates `msvc_runtime` with `[vc14]` correctly. So, the first suggestion dos not appear to be the issue.

The issue might not be reproducible, as a totally fresh install of a Python 3.5 environment suddenly worked again.

Comment: Great - but is vcruntime140.dll in the env\your_env_name\ folder?  You can have different runtimes in different environments (for different Python versions).  Can you show the output of ```echo %PATH%``` in your activated environment, please?

Comment: I can't, since I overwrote that environment to use `python=3.4.3` instead! I cloned it into a new `test` environment and am upgrading that to `python=3.5` to verify if the issue persists.

Edit: it did not. I'm not sure where the hitch was but it appears to be completely smoothed out now. Apologies for the headache. Here is the `echo %PATH%` output:

http://pastebin.com/UZKq9fAE