# Conda attempts to install a large default library into new environments

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I created a fresh install of `Anaconda` (https://www.continuum.io/downloads#all) on my Mac. I then attempted to run `conda create --name test` to create a new virtual environment. It wants to install a **lot** of default packages:

```
cffi:           1.2.1-py27_0  defaults
cryptography:   1.0.2-py27_0  defaults
cssselect:      0.9.1-py27_0  defaults
enum34:         1.1.1-py27_0  defaults
idna:           2.0-py27_0    defaults
ipaddress:      1.0.14-py27_0 defaults
libxml2:        2.9.2-0       defaults
libxslt:        1.1.28-2      defaults
lxml:           3.5.0-py27_0  defaults
nose:           1.3.7-py27_0  defaults
openssl:        1.0.2d-0      defaults
pip:            7.1.2-py27_0  defaults
pyasn1:         0.1.9-py27_0  defaults
pycparser:      2.14-py27_0   defaults
pyopenssl:      0.15.1-py27_1 defaults
python:         2.7.11-0      defaults
queuelib:       1.2.2-py27_0  defaults
readline:       6.2-2         defaults
scrapy:         1.0.3-py27_0  defaults
setuptools:     19.1.1-py27_0 defaults
six:            1.10.0-py27_0 defaults
sqlite:         3.8.4.1-1     defaults
tk:             8.5.18-0      defaults
twisted:        15.5.0-py27_0 defaults
w3lib:          1.12.0-py27_0 defaults
wheel:          0.26.0-py27_1 defaults
zlib:           1.2.8-0       defaults
zope.interface: 4.1.3-py27_0  defaults
```

I have no idea where these are coming from. Furthermore, because `scrapy` is Python 2.x only, `conda` auto-fails when attempting to create a fresh Python 3.x environment (via `conda create --name test python=3.5`):

```
Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
    - python 3.5*
    - scrapy
```

I had had this error in the past (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190272/installing-flask-without-scrapy). At the time I had assumed that there was something wrong on *my* end, perhaps with my Python install. Now I'm not so sure: the Anaconda install on my machine is literally minutes old, and the exact same install on my PC went off without this hitch (albeit with a different one: [Conda Python environment missing DLL file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363125/conda-python-environment-missing-dll-file-on-windows)). IN that case the only things that are installed in a fresh environment are `msvc_runtime`, `pip`, `python`, `setuptools`, and `wheel`, as expected.

What should I do to try to debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you provide should fail, but it seems you have default packages set:

```
msarahan@0109-msarahan-2  ~  conda create --name test
Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file

You can specify one or more default packages to install when creating
an environment.  Doing so allows you to call conda create without
explicitly providing any package names.

To set the provided packages, call conda config like this:

conda config --add create_default_packages PACKAGE_NAME
```

To unset these default packages, look in your ~/.condarc

Edit: .condarc is not removed when uninstalling/reinstalling Anaconda or Miniconda.  This is good and bad.  It saves your settings, but at the same time, it makes it hard to get to a "clean" state.

Comment: I found and deleted the file and everything was as expected once more. Thank you!

For the record, I think it's extremely bad form to leave a file like that just lying around on the computer. At the very least an option should be provided for doing so or not doing so, as I know e.g. the Eclipse uninstaller does.

Comment: I agree. I'll put in an issue as a feature request.  I think part of the issue is that many people treat simply removing the install folder as "uninstall" which of course leaves this file. There should be a proper uninstall script.

Comment: You don't need to put the .condarc file in the home folder, you can put it inside the conda directory and it works too.